# Run WebDriver Script on InternetExplorer 11

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run Webdriver code on Internet explorer but getting error
    
    `Started InternetExplorerDriver server (32-bit)
    2.53.1.0
    Listening on port 21520
    Only local connections are allowed
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException`

Then I googled my problem and do the following fix :-
    `

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.internetExplorer();  
caps.setCapability(InternetExplorerDriver.INTRODUCE_FLAKINESS_BY_IGNORING_SECURITY_DOMAINS,true);
`
```

Also,
I set IE Zoom to 100% and Set Protection mode to enable.
Create Dword BFCACHE using Regedt32.exe
but still IE show me same error.
Please help. I don't understand what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

For internet explorer you need to give path of standalone server of IE.
Download standalone server for IE 11 and place into somewhere so you can point in your code

change your code

```
File file = new File("D:/iexploredriver.exe");
System.setProperty("webdriver.ie.driver", file.getAbsolutePath());
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
```

For more information why we require stanalone server for IE and chrome, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285698/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-system-property-for-chrome-and-ie-browser-and-not-for/35285964#35285964).