# Selenium WebDriver possible to work without System.setProperty(path to driver)?

Tags: java, maven, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I using Java with Selenium WebDriver and I wondered is it possible to remover e.g.

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", dirPath + "\\src\\test\\resources\\geckodriver.exe");
```

and swap this into import library to maven? I saw on mvnrepository this library

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
</dependency>
```

and is it possible to remove System.setProperty and add this dependency?

Comment: You may want to take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285698/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-system-property-for-chrome-and-ie-browser-and-not-for

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager, which will do this part for you. For example:

```
WebDriverManager.getInstance(ChromeDriver.class).setup();
```

It'll download latest `chromedriver` into `.m2` folder and automatically set required system property.

Comment: As long as I remember, this is not supported anymore. Selenium forces you to set your driver path.

Comment: @Nerzid what do you mean by "not supported"? `WebDriverManager` does the same thing implicitly. Chrome property: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/master/src/main/resources/webdrivermanager.properties#L10 Value retrieval: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/a697a9982c1157d76fe9c89db8e6912e4c3cbe9c/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/ChromeDriverManager.java#L52 Property setter: https://github.com/bonigarcia/webdrivermanager/blob/a697a9982c1157d76fe9c89db8e6912e4c3cbe9c/src/main/java/io/github/bonigarcia/wdm/BrowserManager.java#L733

Comment: Thanks it's work properly. I have one more question do you know why I must set OperaOptions op = new OperaOptions();
   op.setBinary(new File("C:\\Program Files\\Opera\\47.0.2631.55\\opera.exe")); without it opera doesn't work?

Comment: @MateuszSobczak see https://github.com/operasoftware/operachromiumdriver/issues/9

Comment: @SergeyKorol For linux system should I set some parameter?

Comment: @MateuszSobczak not sure what parameter do you mean. Could you clarify your question?