# Maven Project - Do we require set property while writing Automation script?

Tags: selenium, maven

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Locators {

public static void main(String ars[]) throws InterruptedException {
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.get("https://www.google.com");
    Thread.sleep(5000);
    driver.close();
}
```

}

Getting this error...

> ```
> >     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The path to the driver executable The path to the driver executable
> ```
>
> must
> > be set by the webdriver.chrome.driver system property; for more
> > information, see
> > https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver. The latest
> > version can be downloaded from
> > http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.internal.Require$StateChecker.nonNull(Require.java:280)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:142)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:37)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:222)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService$Builder.build(DriverService.java:419)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(ChromeDriverService.java:119)
> >         at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:41)
> >         at Selenium.SeleniumPrograms.Locators.main(Locators.java:10)

Comment: And i am using Maven, so do i still require setproperty to be configured?

Answer (score 1):

yes you need to. Executable should be available to selenium to perform UI operations.

```
// Configuring the system properties of chrome driver
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Selenium-java\\chromedriver_win32chromedriver.exe");
```

This may not be required for Firefox. see this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285698/why-do-we-need-to-set-the-system-property-for-chrome-and-ie-browser-and-not-for)

Comment: then how about chrome dependencies ? arent they work in this case ?

Comment: use chrome options for that. btw what is your requirement ?